# Windows 7 64-bit installation from alternative media (no DVD/USB Flash drive)

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation, 64-bit

Greetings

I currently have Windows 7 x86 installed on my computer. I want to install Windows 7 x64 on a different partition on my computer. However there is a little issue, I cannot run the x64 install from Windows 7 x86 which I currently have.

I was planning to Install Windows 7 x64 on another partition to then boot up from that partition to install it on the partition I actually want my OS on. Once that is complete I could just format the partition from the Windows 7 x64 that I didn't need anymore. But the installer will not run from the x86 version of Windows 7 even though I do not want to upgrade that Windows directly.

The reason I'm doing this in such a weird way is that my optical drive is broken and I'm really not into buying a new one since I would use it like once every year or so. I also don't have a USB Flash Drive which is big enough to hold the installation files.

As far as I'm aware I cannot use an external hard drive such as [this one](http://www.wdc.com/en/products/products.aspx?id=440), which I do have. Are there any alternatives in which I can install Windows 7 x64 or am I forced into buying a USB Flash Drive or  new optical drive?

Thank you in advance for your replies.

Edit:
[image: Partitions]

This picture shows my current partitions on my laptop. I want to get Windows 7 x64 on the C partition but have to install it first on the F partition to then boot up the F partition windows to format C and install x64 on that one. My external drive is J.

Edit 2: No alternative computer which has a DVD drive, install files are located on an iso from MA3D. To install my 32 bit version I mounted the ISO in Daemon Tools to replace my Windows Vista but since I cannot run 64 bit into my 32 bit OS this doesn't work.

Edit 3:
[image: cmd bootsect]
Following [this guide](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-install-windows-7vista-from-usb-drive-detailed-100-working-guide/) the above screenshot shows me another problem. I cannot update my USB external HDD with BOOTMGR compatible code because I'm on x86 Windows 7. Seems I'm forced into buying a new optical drive after all.

Edit 4:
I'm going to try to create the boot HDD with the setup files in a virtual machine with the x64 windows 7 installed.

Edit 5:
Solution in **my** case: Installed a virtual machine with x64 then made the USB external into the boot device and installed it. So this solved my problem.

Comment: Why can't you just boot from the CD and run from there? It should let you multiboot, afaik the bootloader doesn't care about the OS architecture...

Comment: My DVD drive is broken :P. It only runs a few DVD's/CD's.

Comment: Do you have a spare computer that you can set up as a server to boot up over LAN?

Comment: I don't think my other PC has a DVD drive either, it's pretty old. Oh well guess I'm forced into buying hardware I'll only use once!

Comment: Since your optical drive is broken, I assumed you were using an ISO or other CD Image file along with an image mounting utility. Running on this assumption, I then assumed you could set up the boot server software on another computer and transfer the cd image file.

Comment: I have no experience regarding this and don't even know if it was possible. Is there any tutorial which could help me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "burn" a Windows 7 .ISO to a USB drive & install from there, http://store.microsoft.com/help/iso-tool.

AFAIK, so long as Windows (your BIOS actually) can see your Passport - as a boot device, you should be able to use that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can upgrade from 32-bit to 64-bit so the only option for you is to run setup from boot. You will need to make the partition before this so that you can keep your x86 file system intact.

I am not up to date on software that can perform a live disk partition as most people do a format to do this. Have a look on Google, they are normally easy to find.

Comment: I know you cannot directly upgrade from 32 to 64, I don't want to do that either :P. The problem is that I cannot use a DVD or USB Flash drive. I'm looking for alternatives if they exist! Edited my question to show you my current partition situation.

Comment: only other option then is move hard drive to another comp/laptop you can use a disk in or try research how to over the network i have never tried this but hear it can cause problems

Comment: ok now i am confused after reading your post you say you have tired to load win 7 64 setup from your 32bit but the only way to open any windows setup from an original install is for upgrade only

Comment: why can you not use a dvd drive ? if you are not using any dvd or usb how are you attempting to run this setup file

Comment: I have an iso file from MA3D.

Comment: find some one with a similar laptop ie. if yours is intel them find some one with similar age intel or same for amd unscrew the one or two screws holding flap on bottom of laptop remover and repeat on friends laptop swapping his old one with yours but make sure you have a partition ready done or you will only be able to format to allow for install

Comment: that is why the way you have been trying is not working even if when u try to open the setup the comp dose reboot dos will not read a iso

Comment: I'm trying to run the setup in my Windows 7 x86, not during the boot since I have no device which is supported to run as boot device(that is actually working properly).

Comment: even when you install from an original windows say for example you are just upgrading windows you can not do this from a iso as it still ned to reboot and load using dos which wont reconize your iso  lol

Comment: I'm not trying to use the iso directly to boot up, if you have read my question. I have the setup files but I cannot use a DVD (in other words burn the iso on a dvd to then use the dvd) or use the setup files on a USB flash drive to set the USB as bootable device. So I'm looking for alternative options if they exist.

Comment: there is no way for you to do this not installing from boot your only two options is use a droner laptops dvd drive  or spare comp over the network                                                      if you use a droner laptop dvd drive to put needed windows files on then do not let it run more than once after first boot this allows windows to find drivers better when u replace hard drive in your own laptop

Comment: you need to read you can only run this setup from a boot no other way to do it live i ever heard of can i ask why can u not use a usb im a lil confussed why you cant

Comment: you can get a usb to install from a iso you just have to extract the iso :)

Comment: AND IT IS THE SETUP FILE THAT REBOOTS THE COMP WHICH IS WHY U CANT DO IT LIKE YOU ARE TRYING

Comment: I don't have a USB flash drive only an external HDD. I just don't want to buy hardware for one time usage, it's a waste of money :). But thanks for your replies. I know what you mean by the bootable stuff you wrote but you don't have to repeat yourself 8x or something :P. And I've already done it the way I did before with 32 bit version :).

Comment: use your portable hdd

Comment: Will it work? I have used this program to make a drive a bootable drive but it didn't recognize my external HDD as a valid drive so I thought it wasn't possible. Any way in the right direction if it is possible?

Comment: what type of portable is it first and try this ;         in start menu search search for disk man then click create and format hard drive partitions  once open find rem drive and right click mark as active try this and have you tried using something along line of deamon tools to make a fake dvd drive on your removable drive then try burn iso if not try mount your iso

Comment: WD My passport as linked in my question. And you haven't linked anything in your comment btw :P

Comment: try above post and let me know

Comment: Thank you for replies but alas no luck :)! Edit 3 will explain everything.

Comment: what happend when you clicked it as active drive did the bios register it ?